# How to call NSURLSession Delegate in NSObject class not in viewcontroller?

Tags: objective-c

```
NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:(id<NSURLSessionDelegate>)self delegateQueue:nil];

NSString *body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bodyData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
RMLog(@"RestManager:[%@]\nRequest URL = %@\nMethod = %@\nHeaders\n%@\nBody\n%@",  keyPath, url.absoluteString, method, additionalHeaders, body);


if (bodyData != nil && ([method isEqualToString:kMethodPost] || [method isEqualToString:kMethodPut])) {
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask =
    [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                          fromData:bodyData
                 completionHandler: ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                     [self parseKeyPath:keyPath responseData:data reponse:response error:error completionHandler:completionHandler];
                 }];
    [uploadTask resume];
}
```

I am trying to call Nsurlsession delegate in NSObject class. I am using this line `NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:(id<NSURLSessionDelegate>)self delegateQueue:nil]` but delegate method is not called.

Answer (score 1):

init your NSObject-Class and set it as the Sessions Delegate...

```
NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:NSObjectClass delegateQueue:nil];
```

in NSObjectClass:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Object : NSObject <NSURLSessionDelegate, ...>

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a NSObject class as below

```
    @interface ServerAPI : NSObject<NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>
   -(void)startUploadTask;
    @end

    @implementation ServerAPI
    -(void)startUploadTask{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];// here you can use your own custom configuration
        NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:(id<NSURLSessionDelegate>)self delegateQueue:nil];

        NSString *body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bodyData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        RMLog(@"RestManager:[%@]\nRequest URL = %@\nMethod = %@\nHeaders\n%@\nBody\n%@",  keyPath, url.absoluteString, method, additionalHeaders, body);
        if (bodyData != nil && ([method isEqualToString:kMethodPost] || [method isEqualToString:kMethodPut])) {
            NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask =
            [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                  fromData:bodyData
                         completionHandler: ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                             [self parseKeyPath:keyPath responseData:data reponse:response error:error completionHandler:completionHandler];
                         }];
            [uploadTask resume];
        }
    }
    // Implement delegates method here
    @end
```

And create instance of ServerAPI class wherever you want and call startUploadTask method.
For example:

```
ServerAPI *instance = [ServerAPI alloc] init];
[instance startUploadTask];
```